# SQLite Operation Inside AlertDialog Doesn't Work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am make activity to update and delete data from sqlite, first app shows alert dialog to shows option delete or update the data of sqlite, but every i update or delete the database, it seems doesn't work.

this is my adapter code :

```
  adapter.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                DataFormNotaPesanan ambil = data.get(position);
                final String kodebarang = ambil.getKode();
                System.out.println("Kode barang: " + kodebarang);
                CharSequence pilihan[] = new CharSequence[] {"Ubah Jumlah", "Hapus"};
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditFormNotaPesanan.this);
                alert.setTitle("Pilih Tindakan");
                alert.setItems(pilihan, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(which==0){
                            AlertDialog.Builder ubah = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditFormNotaPesanan.this);
                            View tampil = EditFormNotaPesanan.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.editjumlah, null);
                            ubah.setTitle("Masukkan Jumlah");
                            ubah.setView(tampil);
                            final EditText jumlah = (EditText)tampil.findViewById(R.id.jumlah);
                            ubah.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    String jumlahpesanan = jumlah.getText().toString();
                                    if(jumlahpesanan.equals("")){
                                        jumlah.setError("Can't blank");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        helper.ubahJumlahNotaPesanan(kodebarang, jumlahpesanan);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            ubah.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            });

                            ubah.show();
                        }
                        else if(which==1){
                            AlertDialog.Builder konfirmasi = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditFormNotaPesanan.this);
                            konfirmasi.setTitle("Delete Data?");
                            konfirmasi.setMessage("Are You Sure Delete: " + helper.getNamaBarang(kodebarang));
                            konfirmasi.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    helper.hapusBarangPesanan(kodebarang);
                                }
                            });
                            konfirmasi.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            });
                            konfirmasi.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

And This is my DataBaseHelper :

```
 public void ubahJumlahNotaPesanan(String kodebarang, String jumlah){
        String query = "update tmp_orderd set jumlah='" + jumlah + "' where ref_barang='" + kodebarang + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void hapusBarangPesanan(String kodebarang){
        String query = "delete from tmp_orderd where ref_barang='" + kodebarang + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_

Comment: After your operation if you reopen your app what happen ?

Comment: @intelliJAmiya nothing happen, data is same

Comment: @sHole the sqlite not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U used notifyDataSetChanged method. This method only trigger when u add or delete object to the arrylist. As here u delete or insert a new data to sqlite u also have to add or remove from arrylist for triggering notifyDataSetChanged method or retrieve data again from sqlite and populate.

Comment: hai, sir. Thanks for your help. Its work! my mistakes should i update my adapter

Comment: if notifyDataSetChanged works then no need to update ur adapter. It will automatically update ur adapter. if not works then u have to update ur adapter.